# Datatables: Search for a specific string when a specific button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

My idea is when button1 is clicked to get input in textare and make search in Datatables.

I need help, hope for understanding.

[image: Sample Button Layout]

my code is this, but I dont get result. I got other ways but i dont want to refresh page:

```
<script src="js/ie/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('input, textarea').placeholder();
  });
</script>
```

and to call it like this:

```
<p class="btn btn-primary" id="myInput" onclick="updateInput('button1')">button1</p>
```

Comment: Where is your datatables implementation?

Comment: you should know how to ask question first, before asking for solution.. we reallty can't help you if you're question is not clear enough

Comment: So you are saying, What ever text is in the search box... When you click the button it will get the .val() of the search box and perform a datatables query am i right?

Comment: @Birdy    YES, example: when you click on button1 it wil be search in that search box : button1.  Same like typing it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have provided almost zero information in your question except for the fact that you want to search the datatable on the click of a button, this should work for you.

```
var oTable = $("#myTable").DataTable();

$("button1").on('click', function(event){
  var searchText = "button1"; //Specific text that you want to search
  oTable.search(searchText).draw();
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UvjnT/1385/)

Comment: Thanks for answer but its not working, I tried this:

`<button class="btn m-b-xs w-xs btn-info" id="button1">button1</button>


<script>
var oTable = $("#example").DataTable();

$("button1").on('click', function(event){
    var searchText = $(this).val();
    oTable.search(searchText).draw();
}
</script>`

Comment: I'm sorry, button doesn't have a `val`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I found how to do it, but dropdown filters wont work then well.

#function
`$("#acctypqee").on('click', function () {
                    table.column(0)
                            .search(this.id)
                            .draw();
                });`

Answer (score 0):

If i am right in thinking you are trying to search for what ever value is in the text area then my below example would get you going..

Word of warning... people are not mind readers and more help from you (The one seeking help) can give us better ideas on what it is you are trying to achieve.

If you are using jQuery as you have tagged that in your OP.

Here jQuery will get the .val() of the input field once you click the button.

```
$("#YourButtonIdHere").click(function(){

    // This will get the value of the search input text box 
    var inputText = $("#myInput").val();

    // Now you can do what you wish, Perform an ajax query?
    // More help from you on what you want to do with the value 
    // from the text box once the button has been clicked 
    // will give me a better chance of helping you!
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I cant get it done. All I want is when button1 is clicked, to make search in the datatables. Its like typing manually in the search box: button1. Sorry hope you can understand.